# Db2 Trigger is triggered even if the condition is doesn't match

Tags: if-statement, triggers, db2

I have an update trigger as following which should ideally trigger on the IF statement and should add the column name if the column entry was modified but my trigger executes even if the condition is not fulfilled . Can someone perhaps point out what i am doing wrong here  ? screenshot following

[image]

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER test_trg_update AFTER
UPDATE
    ON
    test.person REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
        
DECLARE change_type VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE modifier VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE change_time TIMESTAMP;

DECLARE changed_columns VARCHAR(1000);

DECLARE column_name VARCHAR(50);

DECLARE changeuser VARCHAR(50);

SET
changed_columns = '';

IF (n.NAME <> o.NAME) THEN SET
changed_columns = CONCAT (changed_columns,
'NAME,');


ELSEIF (n.PASSWORD <> o.PASSWORD) THEN SET
changed_columns = CONCAT (changed_columns,
'PASSWORD,');



ELSEIF (n.USERNAME <> o.USERNAME) THEN SET
changed_columns = CONCAT (changed_columns,
'USERNAME,');

END IF ;


SET
change_type = 'update';

SET
modifier = (
SELECT
    USER
FROM
    SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1);

SET
change_time = (
VALUES CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

if modifier= 'db2usr' THEN 

INSERT
    INTO
    Test_changelog (change_number,
    change_type,
    table_name,
    identifier,
    entry_type,
    changed_columns,
    modifiers_name,
    change_time)
VALUES (NEXT VALUE FOR TEST_CHANGELOG_SEQ,
change_type,
'test.person',
CONCAT ('id=',
N.ID),
'account',
changed_columns,
modifier,
change_time);
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Your INSERT is fired every time, when current user is `db2usr`. There are no any other conditions for that. Use `WHEN (search-condition)` clause of [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-trigger) to conditionally trigger your code upon update, for example.

Comment: Yes, as @MarkBarinstein says either you add a trigger condition using `WHEN` in the trigger definition or you add logic in the body itself to decide what to do  in each case. The first solution is usually preferred.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein: do i need to change all IF else to when ? I tried changing db2usr part to when but the trigger still does the same . Also if i am gonna use when instead all the IF statements . How will i have a multiple When followed by SET statements  : Example :WHEN (n.NAME <> o.NAME)  SET
changed_columns = CONCAT (changed_columns,
'NAME,');   . Can you share a sample perhaps ?

Comment: `WHEN (n.NAME <> o.NAME or n.PASSWORD <> o.PASSWORD or ...)`. Besides that you use some strange logic for `changed_columns` setting - shouldn't you use independent if-then statements instead of if-then-elseif?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein  : So the requirement is to return the column name if the column was updated . Hence i used if else to figure out if the old column value and new column value is not the same then set changed_column to column name and concatenate the changed columns adding name, password etc if each of this get update at the same time . Does that make sense .

Comment: What do you get in `changed_columns` with your code, if more than one column was updated? You get one column name only, because only one branch of if-then-else is executed. Is such a behavior expected / desired?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein  : I get list of columns updated

Answer (score 0):

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
CREATE TABLE Test_changelog 
(
  change_number     INT NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
, change_type       VARCHAR (50)
, table_name        VARCHAR (128)
, identifier        VARCHAR (50)
, entry_type        VARCHAR (50)
, changed_columns   VARCHAR (128)
, modifiers_name    VARCHAR (128)
, change_time       TIMESTAMP
) IN USERSPACE1
@

CREATE TABLE PERSON 
(
  ID        INT NOT NULL
, NAME      VARCHAR (50)
, PASSWORD  VARCHAR (50)
, USERNAME  VARCHAR (50)
) IN USERSPACE1
@

CREATE OR REPLACE
TRIGGER test_trg_update 
AFTER UPDATE ON person REFERENCING NEW AS N OLD AS O 
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (n.NAME <> o.NAME or n.PASSWORD <> o.PASSWORD or n.USERNAME <> o.USERNAME)
BEGIN ATOMIC
INSERT INTO Test_changelog 
(
  change_number
, change_type
, table_name
, identifier
, entry_type
, changed_columns
, modifiers_name
, change_time
)
VALUES 
(
  DEFAULT
, 'update'
, 'test.person'
, 'id=' || N.ID
, 'account'
-- changed_columns
, SUBSTR 
(
     CASE WHEN n.NAME <> o.NAME         THEN ',NAME'     ELSE '' END 
  || CASE WHEN n.PASSWORD <> o.PASSWORD THEN ',PASSWORD' ELSE '' END
  || CASE WHEN n.USERNAME <> o.USERNAME THEN ',USERNAME' ELSE '' END
, 2
)
, USER
, CURRENT TIMESTAMP
);

END@

INSERT INTO PERSON (ID, NAME, PASSWORD, USERNAME)
VALUES (1, 'N1', 'P1', 'U1')@

UPDATE PERSON 
SET NAME = 'N2', PASSWORD = 'P2'
WHERE ID = 1@

SELECT * FROM Test_changelog@
```

I've simplified the trigger logic a little bit just for convenience.
Note, that you will never get a list of changed columns in db2, if you use your single `IF` statement for all columns, and more than one column is changed. Only one branch of `IF` is executed.